# Can't visible vuetify 'v-select' component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-select, vuetify-1

This is my Home page

```
<template>
<v-form>
 <v-select outlined label="Choose s segment from AI/ML model" :items="item">
 </v-select>
 <v-text-field label="User ID" required></v-text-field>
              
</v-form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      item: ['asv','abc','bcd'],
    };
  },
}

</script>
```

But I running the project select field is not visible.
Why is that? how I do to visible this?
(not shows any errors on the console log)

Comment: pls share console logs error

Comment: not shows any errors on the console log

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere; Check this out: https://codepen.io/mohammadreza-ae/pen/yLVwEzP?editors=1010

Comment: yes. i know this coding is worked correctly. but i want to know why doesn't display in my project?

Comment: why do you have this `</` before closing script tag?

Answer (score 0):

The only error in the code is that you are missing an `'` at `item: ['asv','abc','bcd']`.
Otherwise, it looks fine